# Fix duplicate outputs

Tags: python, import, duplicates, output

I'm trying to run this code, and all seems to be going well, however, the outputs duplicate and I have no clue why. when I remove the check for "main" (the file I'm working in), it doesn't have the same problem and only returns the output once

```
def file_exists(name):
  try:
    exec("import " + name) 
    return True 
  except ModuleNotFoundError:
    return False

#test
print(file_exists("main")) # -> True (file being worked in)
print(file_exists("module1")) # -> True (module exists in program)
print(file_exists("math")) # -> True
print(file_exists("english")) # -> False
```

[image: duplicate outputs]

Comment: It runs perfectly on my machine.

Comment: The code provided cannot produce the output. There are four print statements yet the output has eight lines.

Answer (score 1):

My rough idea is that once `main` runs, it runs all import statements, then u run import again using `exec`, the subsequent imports fail due to double import of same module name. I would print the exception seen - including type and message.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening here is when you include check for "main"

The program runs "import main" in runtime and that actually initialises the main module again

i.e. something like below

```
def file_exists(name):
try:
    exec("import " + name) 
    return True # return true for initial call,#5. True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    return False

#test
print(file_exists("main")) # -> True (file being worked in), this imports the module and initialises it as its not found in sys.modules

"""
def file_exists(name):
   try:
       exec("import " + name) - #a duplicate import so executes and moves to next line
       return True #returns true
   except ModuleNotFoundError:
       return False

   #test
   print(file_exists("main")) #1. True
   print(file_exists("module1")) # -> True (module exists in program), 2.True
   print(file_exists("math")) # -> True, 3.True
   print(file_exists("english")) # 4. False
"""

# after 4th print the control goes back to the check which call the import that will print from (5)
print(file_exists("module1")) # -> True (module exists in program), 6. True
print(file_exists("math")) # -> True, 7.True
print(file_exists("english")) # -> False` 8. True
```

But if we remove check for main none of the above happens and simply 4 checks with one print statement each are executed, thus only 4 lines of print.

Refer - https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Answer (score 0):

OK

1-The problem with running this code too much is that when you import the `main` file, it causes the main file to run twice.

2-The second problem is that the `module1` function is part of the `main` file and must be imported in this way.

```
from main import module1
```

Look at this

```
def module1():
    pass

def file_exists(name):
  try:
    exec(f"import {name}")
    return name, True
  except:
      try:
        exec(f"from main import {name}")
        return name, True
      except Exception:
        return name, False

files=["main", "module1", "math", "english"]
for f in files:
    print(file_exists(f))
```